# How can I get simple plain text from the WMD editor?

Tags: wmd, wmd-editor

I'm able to get Markdown and HTML formated text from the [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) editor. *In my requirement I also need to get plain text from the **WMD** Editor*. I would like to explain it with a simple example.

In Stack Overflow we will see Markdown text while typing a description in the WMD editor. In the preview we are able to see the <b>formatted text. In the Question Page, without this Markdown and formatted text we are able to see the question description in two lines.

I need to achieve same kind of functionality. What do I need to do?

Comment: Maybe you can use `innerText` on the output `<div>`?

Comment: How come when I view this questions from the homepage the article title is "aaaaaaa..." but when I view it here, there is an appropriate title?

Comment: Let me try this.. and will let u know

Answer (score 0):

WMD (or at least [wmd-new](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/), since [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd) seems abandoned) uses jQuery, so the easiest way to get the plain text output is:

```
$('#wmd-preview').text()
```

assuming you're using the standard div id for the preview. This even works as written in Stack Overflow.